# What happen before call to Start_Kernal in Linux Environment

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I just have started reading Device Driver and read Start_kernal function is part of architecture-independent code and has invoked from architecture-dependent part .I wanted to know what actully happens before this start_Kernal routine has called mean to say at booting of kernal.

I'm interested in knowing what happens when newtork device or a USB device interacts with this architecture-dependent code(believe architecture-dependen is first piece of software interact with hardware ).

Is architecture-dependent code is responsibe for fetching information like mac address ,vendor id etc of hardware device attached to system?.

Answer (score 1):

The early kernel code is focused on:

- initializing memory, setting up the MMU and virtual memory;
- initializing clocks and timers;
- initializing the interrupt subsystem;
- configuration of crucial GPIO pins
- retrieving architecture-dependent data, e.g. ARM *ATAG* information.

Note that architecture-dependent initialization does not happen all at once.  A board initialization function can be invoked after the kernel has started but before drivers are initialized.

> newtork device or a USB device interacts with this architecture-dependent code

Network and USB host & gadget devices are represented by device drivers that are initialized much later than that early kernel code.  The "interaction" is minimal, and would conform to the established kernel-driver interface.  A device driver should be written to remove all board-specific dependencies, and replace them with configuration options.  If not, then that driver code should be in the *platform* or *mach* source code directory rather than in the *drivers* directory.

> Is architecture-dependent code is responsibe for fetching information like ...

The MAC address can be passed in the kernel command line, or installed by a bootloader (for retrieval by the device driver).
Vendor ID, board ID and other data can be architecture-dependent code.  For ARM, the kernel receives this information in a memory buffer with [ATAGs](http://www.simtec.co.uk/products/SWLINUX/files/booting_article.html#d0e428).